# package com.facebook does not exist, Facebook Android SDK, IntelliJ Idea

Tags: android, facebook, compilation, intellij-idea

I am trying to write an Android app that uses the Android SDK. I am using IntelliJ Idea 12 CE. I have done this before successfully, but I can't figure out what I did wrong this time. I did the following:

1. I downloaded the Facebook Android SDK from Facebook's developers website and imported that module into IntelliJ, which added it as a library
2. I added the imported library module to my project as a dependency

After that I had no problems writing the code, IntelliJ recognized the imports and everything seemed to work fine. When I tried to compile the code, it gave me the following error for every import statement from com.facebook I had:

> ...package com.facebook does not exist

These are some screenshots I took of the configuration:

[Facebook lib](http://pretechmobile.com/RSVPush.dev/_app_scripts/logosSucursales/facebooklib.png)

[My app's config](http://pretechmobile.com/RSVPush.dev/_app_scripts/logosSucursales/rsvpushconfig.png)

Comment: [Imports are recognized in the editor](http://pretechmobile.com/RSVPush.dev/_app_scripts/logosSucursales/Code.png)
[Console errors](http://pretechmobile.com/RSVPush.dev/_app_scripts/logosSucursales/console.png)
[Facebook module config](http://pretechmobile.com/RSVPush.dev/_app_scripts/logosSucursales/facebookdep.png)
[Facebook module](http://pretechmobile.com/RSVPush.dev/_app_scripts/logosSucursales/facebookmod.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on **java** sub-directory under the newly added module and select **Mark Directory As** and then choose **Sources Root**, might be needed to Rebuild the project.